# Replacing an input button with an image

Tags: html

I am trying to replace my button with an image but no matter what I do it won't change.
here is how I am trying to do it, is there anything wrong with my method?

```
<input id="deal"  class="button" name= "button" type="reset" value="Deal" SRC="/buttons/deal.png" 
     HEIGHT=38 WIDTH=62 
     ALT="Yes" BORDER=0 onclick="startRound();return false;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bro

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Click Me" />
<script>
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("class1");
    });
</script>
```

and the class is here

```
    .class1
    {
        height:40px;
        width:40px;
        background-size:100%;
        color:transparent;
        background-image:url('visual_studio_2012.png');
    }
```

Use any image you want and dont forget to add the jquery plugins

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.buttonStyle {
border: none;
background: #FFF url('deal.png');
}
</style>
<input type="button" class="buttonStyle" value="Button"/>
```

Also check [Changing the Submit Button to an Image](http://www.pardot.com/faqs/html-css/changing-the-submit-button-to-an-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an `onclick` event in the image

```
<img onclick="ImageClick()" ></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good solution. Take a look at the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2wu7cwt/1/).

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.body.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

(button.attachEvent) ? 
button.attachEvent('onclick', function (e) {
    if (button.className === 'button active') {
        button.className = 'button';
    } else {
        button.className = 'button active';
    };
}) :
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (button.className === 'button active') {
        button.className = 'button';
    } else {
        button.className = 'button active';
    };
}, false);
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="reset"] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    font: bold 62px/normal Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="reset"].active {
    background: url('http://careers.microsoft.com/global/careers/EN/AU/PublishingImages/home_hero_au_690x294.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```